# Mod_Rewrite help

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My url pattern is like so:

```
example.com/A/B
```

I want my url condition to be if `A.html` does exist in the cache folder do such and such, I have something like this so far:

```
RewriteCond ^([^/]+)/?([^/]*) /cache/$1.html -f
```

But I know its not the right way of doing it, any help would be appreciated!
Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$N` backreferences in a `RewriteCond` refer to the corresponding `RewriteRule`. So if you include the matching group you need in your `RewriteRule`, you can do:

```
RewriteCond /cache/$1.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?([^/]*) whatever-replacement
```

Alternatively, you can use a `%N` backreference, and include another `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^([^/]+)/?([^/]*)
RewriteCond /cache/%1.html -f
```